# Browser doesn't want to run .js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to run a code that I had found on CodePen, but Chrome and Firefox don't want to run js. I tried different browsers but get the same result. When I inspect element in the browser I get this:

```
script {
display: none;}
```

The code I tried to run can be found here: https://codepen.io/gleamland/pen/KmzrZp

I have add the html code to body tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photo_gallery.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="photo_gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I had copy/paste the js and CSS code from the site in the separate files that are named photo_gallery.css and photo_gallery.js (as that is mentioned above)

Does anyone know why and how to fix that problem?

Comment: try moving it to the just before the end of `body` because the HTML wouldn't have loaded yet. Or you could wrap the JS in a `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {...`

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - There's no reason to add `type` at all, whatsoever.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To better help you, please post relevant all code, and in this case it might be helpful to include the file structure of where you are trying to run this from.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing, that is why I first tried to add script at the end of body but it didn't work. Could there be a problem in something else? I think that the problem is not in the code, because every time when I try to run .js (even with different codes) I get the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add jQuery, Bootstrap and Magnific Popup. Try it this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photo_gallery.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
...
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="photo_gallery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is important to use the `<script>` tags in `<body>` and not in `<head>`, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: tried and the same problem occurs, only this time I get for every script display: none.

Comment: @DobraVila That's because `script` is *never* displayed. Any DOM elements created by a script tag will display where they are told to, and not in the script tag. Therefore `script`'s display status will be none.

Comment: oh, ok didn't know thanks for that :) Now when I have add those two scripts in head tag and photo_gallery.js at the end of the body is working. Thanks for that! Can you just explain me why did I need to add 2 extra scripts?

Comment: @DobraVila I have updated my answer and tested it. Now it should work for you.

Comment: Yeah, it's working, thanks! Can you please explain me why do I need those 2 scripts?

Comment: @DobraVila sure, both script files (jQuery and Magnific Popup) are JavaScript libraries and Bootstrap is a CSS framework. Of course you could write a code without all of them but then you will have much more code than you have now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding these two scripts in the `head` and `<script src="photo_gallery.js"></script>` at the end just before `</body>` tag.

The reason for adding it at the end is because the HTML may not have completely loaded for the JS to work. So, adding it at the end ensures that the HTMLs loaded and the JS can act upon it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photo_gallery.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="photo_gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
...
...
<script src="photo_gallery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```